# Create date table with activity in SQL

Tags: sql, date, view

I currently have a date table linked to my activity table:

Date table example:

[image: Date table]

Also I have an table with activities per day, but there are days in which I don't have any activites:
[image: Activity Table]

I want to create a view where I have all my dates, also including the dates on which I don't have any activities.
For those dates I want to calculate the average of the weekday and add it there, once I have the activities from our WMS I want to replace the data. In this way I can create a average on where we will land for different activities in the current month.

Now I have created the view already but I can't get the missing dates inside this view:
[image: View Example]

How can I ensure that I have the full range of dates for this year and then all the activities for the days. So if I don't have activities from my WMS I want to have a line with:
Date - Activity

Currently I have joined my tables using the following codes:

```
FROM [LOG].[dbo].[DATE_TABLE] b 

JOIN CTE1 c
on b.[date] = c.[date]

JOIN CTE2 D
on c.[Activity]  = d.[Activity]
AND b.[Day_of_Week] = d.[Day_of_Week]

GROUP BY b.[date], b.[Day_Name], c.[Activity],b.[Day_of_Week], d.[Trans], d.[Items], d.[Scans]
```

Comment: Can you share your simple data & expected result as text instead of images, and also tag the DBMS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a join on
JOIN CTE2 D
on c.[Activity]  = d.[Activity]
And CTE1

You could do a left join so if you don’t have an activity from CTE2  or a date from CTE1 you still get the activity and date from date table

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Just for my understanding, what is the difference between LEFT JOIN and normal JOIN?

Comment: Left Join would take all values of a column from table A and look for matches of the same column value from Table B so if table A contains all the dates you want to list and Table B only has few matches of the dates and then you show all the dates from Table A and also the ones you found from Table B .. if you did a join instead of a left join then you would only see dates from Table A And Table B .. leaving missing values. You can read more here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp